# Xamarin android- push notification click deleting SQLite data when app closed

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have integrated FCM push notifications in xamarin android app. When foreground notifications delivering, notification click event calling `MainActivity` and from there it is not receiving and deleting all inserted records of SQLite because of that I am navigating to the wrong page. How can I retrieve my SQLite DB?
Thank you.
My Code:

click_action code:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { "SISActivity" }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryHome, Intent.CategoryDefault })]
public class SISActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
      //from here need to navigation on other pages.
}
```

click_action sending with FCM notification

```
click_action":"SISActivity"
```

But code starting execution from `MainActivity`

Code in main activity for getting **already logged in user**

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection _conn;
   _conn = DatabaseAccess.GetConnection();
   //if table already created sqlite wont create it again
   await _conn.CreateTableAsync<LoggedInUser>();
   var objSisRepo = new SISRepository<LoggedInUser>(_conn);
   var resultSingle = await objSisRepo.Get();
```

**resultSingle** getting 0 even if records available and deleting existing 
 records. Consequently, i am navigating to the login page instead of the Home page.
 It is working fine when the app is in the background. I am using Async programming here.

SQLite connection getting method.

```
public static SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection()
        {
            SQLiteAsyncConnection con = null;
            try
            {
                var sqlDbFileName = "edTheSIS.db3";
                var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqlDbFileName);
                var connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
                con = connection;

                return connection;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Something went wrong", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                var objLog = new LogService();
                objLog.MobileLog(ex, SISConst.UserName);
            }
            return con;
        }
```

Comment: Are you using  `Xamarin.Forms` project?

Comment: No, I am using Xamarin android. Thank you

Comment: I think we'd likely need to see some code to help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: ok sure. but for that where i need to paste the code in the same comment box or i need to edit the question. thank you

Comment: Hi @York Shen where should i post my code, i am new to stack overflow, dont know how to use it properly.

Comment: Post it in your question and also please post your codes in a good format.

Comment: I have posed my code please look over it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this is proper answer or not but near to it, and solved my problem. I was using `AsyncSQLiteConnection` , as I have posted my code. Now I have remove that and just using `SQLiteConnection` it is working for me. Thank you